# javascript to update product total

Tags: javascript

I have am after a way to automatically update the price div (`<span class="amount">$39</span>` ) when the dropdown value is selected (`<option data-price="30.00" value="graphic-design-1">Graphic Design ($30)</option>`)

Both of the above option values are dynamic and is a woocommerce plugin with what I am requiring planned for future releases but I need it now

The price would then be **$69**

The structure of the dropdown is:

```
<select class="addon addon-select" name="addon-artwork">

                <option value="">Select an option...</option>

                <option data-price="30.00" value="graphic-design-1" >Graphic Design (<span class="amount">&#36;30</span>)</option>
                <option data-price="0.00" value="artwork-provided-2" >Artwork provided</option>

</select>
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: @JosephSilber I am still unsure how to update the price as the price is just text were as the option has the "data-price"

Comment: can you use jQuery or should this be js only?

Comment: @Saturnix it can be both its available :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var span = document.getElementsByClassName('amount')[0];
var select = document.getElementsByClassName('addon-select')[0];
var originalPrice = +span.textContent.substr(1);

select.addEventListener('change', function () {
    var price = +select.options[ select.selectedIndex ].getAttribute('data-price');
    span.textContent = '$' + (price + originalPrice);
}, false);
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zgd8G/

---

If you're using jQuery, you can shorten it to this:

```
var $span = $('.amount'),
    originalPrice = +$span.text().substr(1);

$('.addon-select').change(function () {
    var price = +$(this).find('option:selected').data('price');
    $span.text('$' + (price + originalPrice));
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zgd8G/1/

Comment: I have just looked over your fiddles and its not taking the $39 into account so its only showing the $30 when selected when it should show $69

Comment: @JessMcKenzie - Didn't realize that you wanted to add the amounts. I updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Well @JessMcKenzie the fiddle is working perfectly unless you tell us clearly what are you asking about. But I think you will have to work out on the value of 69, like add the formula along with the updating of value. You can always find help here: http://api.jquery.com/